# Rotating about 2 axes independently

Tags: rotation

I am looking for a solution to the following problem:

I have a ball travelling to the upper right corner of the screen. That is, its velocity to the right and up are identical.

To simulate its rotation, it has an angular velocity along the X and the Y axis - those are also both equal.

This works fine so far. My problem is now to correctly *rotate* the ball on display: I am using OpenGL and a simple sphere for the ball.

Now my naive approach was to use

```
glRotate(rx, 1, 0, 0); // rotate about x axis
glRotate(ry, 0, 1, 0); // rotate about y axis
```

But this does not work as I intended: The second rotation depends on the first one. On second thought, this works as I was used to it. But now I am looking for a solution to rotate my ball correctly by applying both rotations independently.

I also tried using quaternions but did not succeed. I am even not sure if I get something completely wrong an my approach of "rotate some degrees about x, then some about y" makes sense at all.

Any "enlightment" is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you try using quaternions that didn't work?  If your implementation is correct, then quaternions should always be correct

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula Axis-angle formula for rotation around an arbitrary axis.

Answer (score 0):

How about `glRotate(rr, 1,1,0);` in that case you rotate around the arbitrary vector (1,1,0).